# Display recent activity to a section of the wiki in an Azure DevOps project

Tags: azure-devops, markdown

We're moving our wikis over to Azure DevOps and want to replicate the 'overview' pages we have for each section of the wiki. This is comprised of a table with links to various files (which was easy enough to create in markdown), followed by a list of recent updates to pages within that section (showing which team member made the update, which page was updated, and the date).

Azure DevOps doesn't appear to let you run queries on wiki pages within a project, which was my initial approach. I therefore need some markdown that will return a list of the above information (say, the last ten updates made to a specified page of the wiki and any of its sub-pages). Is this possible? Or is there a better way to get the result I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Display recent activity to a section of the wiki in an Azure DevOps project

I am afraid this is impossible at this moment.

If you want to return a list of the last ten updates made to a specified page of the wiki and any of its sub-pages, there is a option **View Revisions**, which you could get wiki page history:

> Revision pages show who made the change along with the revision
>   message, date, and version or commit ID. To view details of a
>   revision, select the message or version link.

Check the document [View wiki page history and revert changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-view-history?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

But we could not get the update list for all wiki pages, just for one specify.

Besides, the functions supported by markdown are limited currently, AFAIK, we could not dynamic Wiki Content, if we need to list the update list for all wiki pages, it should be the dynamic content:

Check the user voice [Add dynamic Wiki Content](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/379611/add-dynamic-wiki-content.html).

The way I can think of is that we could create a scripts to invoke REST API to return the updates made to a specified page of the wiki, then add the result to the markdown in the local, and push the changes to the Azure devops. But this will add a update message in the Wiki.

So, I am afraid this is impossible at this moment.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see recent wiki page changes, look in the DevOps Repos -> Commits page in the GUI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: One could go to https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_git/<project>.wiki/commits